# Delete word to the left in WordStar

Tags: wordstar

In WordStar 4.0, is there a control command to delete the word to the left of the cursor?

I know that I can press ^A to move one word to the left and then ^T to delete the word I just moved over, but sometimes I want to delete more than one recently-typed word, and it's cumbersome to do the two commands repeatedly.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity (and cause its quite awesome you're running that museum piece of a word processor) what OS is this running in? Would screenshots be possible?

Comment: I run it on MS-DOS, but it also exists for CP/M. Sure, I can make a screenshot … but of what? A word with the cursor to the right of it? :)

Comment: Yeah. I suspect this is going to be a hot question. Might as well have a little more information. If its good enough for GRRM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an Internet search, I would guess such a command does not exist.

For example, InfoWorld magazine from January 5, 1987, page 68, in a review of a mouse called Summa Mouse, says the following about its driver software:

> The 1-2-3 and Wordstar menus are more complete. The Wordstar menu
>   [...] includes some Wordstar commands we didn't know existed and
>   creates others out of combination commands such as "delete word left"
>   (Ctrl-A, Ctrl-T).

(Source: https://books.google.com/books?id=YTwEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA68&dq=wordstar+%22ctrl-a-ctrl-t%22.)

However, that article is from just before WordStar 4.0 was released.  ("February 1987 saw the release of WordStar 4", see http://www.wordstar.org/index.php/wordstar-history.)  So it is theoretically possible that such a command was added in WordStar 4.

A command like you want does not occur in a list of WordStar 3 commands at [wordstar.org](http://wordstar.org) (http://www.wordstar.org/index.php/wsdos-documentation/wsdos-commands/108-wordstar-3-for-dos-commands-reference; Internet Archive link to an alternative that disappeared: https://web.archive.org/web/20120919041753/http://www.wordstar.org/index.php/wordstar-emulator/support/wordstar-commands/90-wordstar-command-details-a-differences).

I could not find any list of WordStar 4 (or later) commands.

---

Finally, and you probably already know this, I read that WordStar 4 and up support *programmable function keys*, which you could perhaps use for this purpose:

> Wordstar 4 is a vast improvement over [the function key mechanism of
>   WordStar 3.3]: It offers 40 function keys, each capable of handling up
>   to 30 keystrokes (we experimented -- the documentation doesn't say),
>   and patching them only takes a few minutes.

Source: Review of Wordstar 4 by practising psychologist (!) Bernie Zilbergeld in InfoWorld magazine from April 13, 1987, page 50, https://books.google.com/books?id=HDwEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA50&dq=%22function+keys%22.

Finally finally, note that the same review suggests that

> "Real Wordstar users don't use function keys" seems to be the theme.

:-)